# My view runs outside the screen and doesn't shift back down

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4.2

I tried to implement a Notification that alerts the view that the Keyboard will appear and should shift upwards with the keyboards height.

```
func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(KeyboardWillShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}
```

Here is the **KeyboardWillShow** method body:

```
@objc func KeyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    view.frame.origin.y -= getKeyBoardHeight(notification)
}
```

and the **getKeyBoardHeight** function:

```
func getKeyBoardHeight(_ notification: Notification) -> CGFloat {
    let userinfo = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardsize = userinfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue

    return keyboardsize.cgRectValue.height
}
```

Why does my app shift completely out of view and when I toggle the keyboard on in the simulator?

Comment: What is `view` in the KeyboardWillShow method?

Comment: Don't move all the view, move only the subview that are covered by the keyboard.

Comment: `view.frame.origin.y -= getKeyBoardHeight(notification)` is moving your view down. Use `+=` instead :)  Positive = up/right | Negative = down/left

Comment: And reset the changes into the `keyboardWillHide` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the methods I use on a regular basis that work, I think your issue is with using `-= getKeyboardHeight`, try the code in my `keyboardWillShow` method below

```
class VC: UIViewController {

    func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    func unsubscribeFromKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        view.frame.origin.y = -getKeyboardHeight(notification: notification)
    }

    func getKeyboardHeight(notification: NSNotification) -> CGFloat {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo
        let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
        return keyboardSize.cgRectValue.height
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works ! I would appreciate it if you clarify to me why  -= getKeyboardHeight wasn't working correctly

Comment: I am not 100% sure, if the keyboard height was 200, using -getKeyboardHeight the origin would be -200. using -= it would be -200 the first time the keyboard launched but if you dont reset it back to 0, the next time it would be -400 and keep moving furhter away each time the notification was received. you might be receiving the notification multiple times, are you setting first repsonders manually or something? using -getKeyboardHeight is more specific anyway, you want the view to move up by the height of the keyboard exactly

Comment: please accept the answer if it fixes your issue so the question can be closed